# RMS of signal vs average amplitude

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, power-spectral-density, amplitude

I am trying to estimate the average amplitude of some signal with frequency 6 Hz, sampled at ~300 Hz. See figures for a part of the signal and its dft calculated using matlab.

I estimate the average amplitude of the signal by calculating its root mean square,

```
>> rms(signal)

ans =

    5.1651
```

However, when looking at the signal (see first figure), it is very clear the mean amplitude is slightly greater than ~5, and is probably closer to ~8. Summing the peak amplitude in the frequency domain and its first few aliases results in the same value (~5).

What am I doing wrong here? How to properly estimate the signal average amplitude from its dft?

[image: Signal]

[image: fft]

Comment: As a rough comparison, the RMS of a pure tone is 0.707 of its amplitude.  So, divide your 5 by it and you get 7.07.  (Challenge: Where does the 707 come from and why does it repeat?)  Likewise, double your DFT magnitude for that bin and you get roughly the same answer.

Comment: Nah, that's all there is to it.

$$ 0.707 \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $$

$$ \frac{5}{0.707}  \approx \frac{ \frac{10}{2} }{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} = 10 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $$

10 times makes the repeat.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to make a few guesses but realized they don't make sense. Thanks again!

Comment: You are most welcome.  You seem to have a good attitude about this stuff so keep up the good work.

Comment: In case you didn't know, doubling the magnitude of the bin to get the amplitude only works if your tone has a whole number of cycles in the frame.  If not, a good approach is this https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/787.php, but it is a lot easier just to frame a whole number of cycles (at least five).    If you try the approach in the article, I recommend that you "unfurl" the vectors like I do here: https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1284.php.